# Date format is different on servers

Tags: tfs, ssas, ssas-2012

We have a production and test environment of TFS 2013 Update 2. When I browse the `Team System` cube and browse to `Date -> Year Week Date -> Members -> All -> 2014 -> Week ending 13 april`, the dates have different format than the test environment.

The production environment has the format: 13-04-14 (day month year).
The test environment has the format: 18-10-2006 (day month year).
Another TFS environment has the format: 04-13-2014 (month day year).

How is the format set? And how can I get them the same? How is it set? It is a default TFS 2013 installation. 
The regions of the server are the same...

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Language/Collation property of the Analysis Server and the default collation property of SQL Server instance

Answer (score 0):

I checked the region settings of the user that is running my TFS Server. So I connected with remote desktop and saw that the region was different. I changed the region so they are the same and rebooted the server (reboot was needed). I then did a rebuild of the cube. Now they are both dutch (dd-MM-yyyy) and everything is working again.